# How to run mysql as non root user?

Tags: mysql

I need to install /run mysql enterprise in production environment as non root user. Idea is to manage mysql without giving root/sudo  access to DBA. Is that possible with rpm installation ? if Yes, Is it recommended way ?

Comment: This question has nothing to do with programming, therefore it is off topic here on SO. Database administration questions have their own site: dba.stackexchange.com

Comment: ok...sure..Thanks for info.....Actually I'm writing ansible playbook for the same. That's why I thought I can put here

Comment: look for a tarball distribution of MySQL Enterprise. They are easier to deal with as non-root.

Comment: YAML is also a borderline area because it is not programmin / scripting either, it is a hierarchical set of data, which is translated by ansible into instructions. If you have a question about YAML syntax, that's fine on SO. If you are asking how to configure a database, that's not.